# One page form, on mobile I will need scrolling-type questionnaire with one item per page

Tags: html

I am new to bootstrap, I have a limited knowledge on bootstrap. A little hints or an idea to achieve the following requirement will be great favor to me.

I have a registration form  where user can fill it and submit it for registration process. So, On the desktop I want a one page form, on mobile I will need scrolling-type questionnaire with one question per page.

Thanks

Comment: Post what you have tried until now

Comment: Please post related code and fiddle if possible